# Numpy median precision issues at scale

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision, median

In my experiment, I have a large 2D `np.ndarray` `X` of type `float64` of dimensions 25x431080. I want to calculate the element-wise median across the 0-axis to get an array of dimensions 1x431080. Assume that I distort a row of the original array such that the median should not be affected, e.g., assign it to a value out of the range of the original elements. My problem is that the median computation won't return the exact same array as before.

I am wondering whether this is a typical precision issue. Is there is any way around it perhaps with another type or function?

I am attaching here a randomly generated example s.t. one can reproduce the issue

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.uniform(-1,1,(25,431080))
med1 = np.median(x, axis = 0)
x[13,:] = -100*np.ones(x.shape[1]) # distort one row to -100
med2 = np.median(x, axis = 0)
np.array_equal(med1, med2) # returns False
```

Note: re-computation of the median on the same array gives exactly the same result so there is no precision loss or any other change across different runs of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that your assumption is correct.
Why should changing a value of the array to -100 not also change the median?

```py
while True:
    x1 = np.round(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 10), 2)
    x2 = x1.copy()
    x2[3] = -100

    m1 = np.median(x1)
    m2 = np.median(x2)
    
    if m1 != m2:
        print(x1)
        print(x2)
        print(m1, m2)
        break
```

Or maybe even simpler: an example array `[1, 2, 3]` with the median `2`.
Changing one of the initial values to `-100` in general also changes the median. But sometimes you are lucky. If you change a value smaller than the median with `-100`
the median stays the same, but if you exchange a value larger or equal to the median, the median changes.

```py
x1 = [1,    2,    3] -> 2
x2 = [-100, 2,    3] -> 2
x3 = [1, -100,    3] -> 1
x4 = [1,    2, -100] -> 1
```